# Get value from clicked button with modals

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of elements in a table. If a button is clicked a modal pops up and to show some content in that modal i need to get the id of the element that was clicked. How can i do that?

```
<div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse">
    <div class="accordion-inner">
        <form action="" method="post">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="25%"><strong>Options</strong></td>
                        <td width="25%"><strong>Block id</strong></td>
                        <td width="25%"><strong>Block type</strong></td>
                        <td width="25%"><strong>Block order</strong></td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <button data-toggle="modal" id="editBlockBtn" data-target="#editBLock" data-block-id="8" class="btn btn-warning btn-mini"></button> 
                            <button data-toggle="modal" id="editBlockBtn" data-target="#deleteBlock" data-block-id="8" class="btn btn-danger btn-mini"></button></td>
                        <td>8</td>
                        <td>image</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <button data-toggle="modal" id="editBlockBtn" data-target="#editBLock" data-block-id="9" class="btn btn-warning btn-mini"></button> 
                            <button data-toggle="modal" id="deleteBlockBtn" data-target="#deleteBlock" data-block-id="9" class="btn btn-danger btn-mini"></button></td>
                        <td>9</td>
                        <td>image</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Which `<td>` do you want to get?

Comment: You're asking a question based around html and JavaScript, please show the generated (relevant/[mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) html; not the php script that generates it.

Comment: Updated with source dom :)

Answer (score 0):

You can just write the ID again into a data-attribute on each button. Then you have easy access using jquery's data method. Like so:

PHP:

```
<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editBLock" data-block-id="<?php echo $block['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-warning btn-mini"><i class="icon-edit icon-white"></i></button>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('button').click(function() {
   var clickedId = $(this).data('block-id');
});
```

If you can not change your PHP code, and the structure in your table is fixed, you can do it like this:

```
$('button').click(function() {
   var clickedId = $(this).parent().next('td').text();
});
```

Comment: Updated the thread with data-block-id included, but i can't seem to get the id with your solution.

Comment: Just tested it with your updated html, seems to be fine. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/aLz6q4x0/

Answer (score 0):

**first:** `id=""` is Unique, You can not use it twice in two elements. so change These to classes: `editBlockBtn` and `deleteBlockBtn`.

so if you want to get the `<td>`'s content It is better to add them a class like:

```
<td class="Block-id">9</td>
<td class="Block-type">image</td>
<td class="Block-order">2</td>
```

now You can easily get the [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) `<tr>` parent (or just use [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)):

```
$('.editBlockBtn').click(function() {
    var parentTr = $(this).closest('tr');
});
```

then you can get the content:

```
var block_id = parentTr.find('.Block-id').text();
var block_type = parentTr.find('.Block-type').text();
var block_order = parentTr.find('.Block-order').text();
```

**demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gbpkxbvv/**